# Python: I am getting a syntax error that prevents me from deploying me contract. What is the syntax of format that I need to use for this?

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, python, brownie, external-api

I just created a new API key for Etherscan. I added my key to my .env file, and I added `publish_source=True` to `print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}"), publish_source=True` to be able to verify my contract. The problem is that I get an error when I deploy my contract.

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

It prevents me from deploying my contract as a whole. How should I format this print statement, and what is the reason for the error - I assume that this either changes somewhere in a Python or Etherscan API update.

Link to GitHub Repo: https://github.com/yarg-eth/Brownie_Fund_Me

Comment: This question is missing relevant source code and tracebacks and is unanswerable.

Comment: Should I attach all of the scripts that are in my project? There are only two of them.

Comment: @GrayBlanchard If they are short you could add them to the question if they are long you can link to a github repo.

Comment: I probably send a link to a GitHub repo just so that everything is there.

Comment: Added the Github repo. Everything that I have dealt with is in the scripts and contracts folder, and dependency and build data are in the other folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `publish_source=True` when you are deploying your contract and not when you are printing something.

So in your `deploy_fund_me()` function on lines 6 and 7 make the following changes.

```
fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account}, publish_source=True)

print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")
```

Comment: After reviewing what I did. I found that I was being acting very haphazardly and was probably really tired when I submitted this question. Very simple that I just added publish_source=True on the wrong line of code.